# How to handle search parameter in Datatables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have the following code :

**Controller method**

```
public JsonResult GetNonstandardProgram(
    int draw, 
    int start, 
    int length, 
    string search = null /* or string search or string[] search = null */
    )
```

**Posted data by datatables**

```
...&search%5Bvalue%5D=somethingToSearch&search%5Bregex%5D=false
```

and I dont know how to handle this part

```
&search[value]=somethingToSearch
```

because in *Controller* passed string parameter 'search' is allways null.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does 
...&search=test work?

Why are you putting search[value] ?

Comment: datatables is posting this data, how can i change that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, solution is to use

```
[Bind(Prefix = "search[value]")] string search
```

as parameter input